# Extract list of values associated with specific header within an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I would like to have a function that can extract from an expression a list of values that are within the brackets of a certain header at any level:

```
HeaderContent[Expression_, Header_]
```

For example consider `expr=a[b[q],c[{b[w],m[{d,f,g}],y[s]}],d[u],m[p]];`, so that

```
HeaderContent[expr,m]
```

> {{d,f,g},p}

Does this function exist? If not, how could one implement it?

Comment: `Extract[expr, Position[expr, m[___]]] /. m[a___] :> a` ?

Comment: `Cases[expr, m[a___] :> a, Infinity]`?

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cases[expr, m[a___] :> a, Infinity]
(* {{d,f,g},p}*)
```

Be careful with

```
expr = m@m@p;
Cases[expr, m[a___] :> a, Infinity]
(* {p} *)
```

versus

```
expr = m@m@p;
Cases[expr, m[a___] :> a, {0, Infinity}]
(* {p, m[p]} *)
```